# PHP SQL No result returned

Tags: php, sql

$block is not being returned. The problem seems to arise during the while statement. I have used this script before, only slightly different, so i know it is something fairly minor. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['filter_tag'])) {
    $filter_tag = $_GET['filter_tag'];
}

    if (@mysql_connect('xxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxx')) {
        if (mysql_select_db('xxxxx')) {
                $query = " SELECT blocks . CNO, blocks . CName, blocks . URL, images . Ipath FROM blocks LEFT JOIN images ON blocks . INO = images . INO WHERE CNO LIKE 'mysql_real_escape_string($filter_tag)' ";
        $query_run = mysql_query($query);
        } while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {      
            echo $block =   '<li id="'.$query_row['CNO'].'" class="block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#blocklModal" >
        <a href="'.$query_row['URL'].'" target="_blank">
        <img class="b" src="'.$query_row["Ipath"].'" alt="" data-controls-modal="block-modal" data-backdrop="static">
        </a>
        <p class="c-title">'.$query_row['Name'].'</p>
        </li>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: remove @ from @mysql_connect('xxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxx')

Comment: I doubt `LIKE 'mysql_real_escape_string($filter_tag)'` ever worked correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work (as long as your query is correct).  Just know that mysql_* is depreciating and you should really use PDO or MySQLi to run your queries.  This answer will be useless in the near future:

```
if (isset($_GET['filter_tag'])) {
    $filter_tag = $_GET['filter_tag'];

    if (mysql_connect('xxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxx')) {
        if (mysql_select_db('xxxxx')) {
            $filter_tag = mysql_real_escape_string($filter_tag);
            $query = " SELECT blocks . CNO, blocks . CName, blocks . URL, images . Ipath FROM blocks LEFT JOIN images ON blocks . INO = images . INO WHERE CNO LIKE '$filter_tag'";
            $query_run = mysql_query($query);
            while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
                $block =  '<li id="' . $query_row['CNO'] . '" class="block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#blocklModal">';
                $block .= '<a href="' . $query_row['URL'] . '" target="_blank">';
                $block .= '<img class="b" src="' . $query_row["Ipath"] . '" alt="" data-controls-modal="block-modal" data-backdrop="static">';
                $block .= '</a><p class="c-title">' . $query_row['Name'] . '</p></li>';
                echo $block;
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'No filter tag provided';
}
```

Try checking out this link to learn more about PDO/MySQLi: [PDO vs MySQLi - Which Should You Use](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/)